# make MessageDigest and Cipher equivalent to java.security.Signature

Tags: java, rsa, digital-signature, sha1, java-security

I want to implement my own signature function using RSA as a cipher algorithm and SHA-1 as a hash function, to do so I implemented those two function:

```
public byte[] mySign(byte[] aMessage){
    try{
        // get an instance of a cipher with RSA with ENCRYPT_MODE
        // Init the signature with the private key
          Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
          cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, this.thePrivateKey);

        // get an instance of the java.security.MessageDigest with sha1
             MessageDigest meassDs = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

        // process the digest
             meassDs.update(aMessage);
             byte[] digest = meassDs.digest();

            byte [] signature = cipher.doFinal(digest);

        // return the encrypted digest
        return signature;

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()+"Signature error");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}



public boolean myCheckSignature(byte[] aMessage, byte[] aSignature, PublicKey aPK){
    try{
        // get an instance of a cipher with RSA with DECRYPT_MODE
        // Init the signature with the public key
          Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
          cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aPK);

        // decrypt the signature
             byte [] digest1 = cipher.doFinal(aSignature);

        // get an instance of the java.security.MessageDigest with sha1
             MessageDigest meassDs = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");

        // process the digest
             meassDs.update(aMessage);
             byte[] digest2 = meassDs.digest();

        // check if digest1 == digest2
        if (digest1 == digest2)
        return true;
        else
            return false;

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Verify signature error");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then when I use those function, I always obtain false as result which means  that my functions are not working right :

```
byte[] message = "hello world".getBytes();
byte[] signature;

signature = mySign(message );
boolean bool = myCheckSignature(message , signature, thePublicKey);
System.out.println(bool);
```

Comment: Why not just use the [Signature class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Signature.html)?

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("RSA");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. Nowadays, you should use OAEP instead of the default PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. So you should probably use `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");`

Comment: Why shouldn't we roll our own? ["You can roll your own, but you probably will make a major security mistake if you are not an expert in security/cryptography or have had your scheme analyzed by multiple experts. I'm more willing to bet on an open-source publicly known encryption scheme that's out there for all to see and analyze. More eyes means less likely that the current version doesn't have major vulnerabilities than something developed in-house by non-experts."](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own)

Comment: I'm no security expert, but I do know that SHA-1 was deprecated at least for creating certificates. Best take caot's advice and don't roll your own!

Comment: In fact I am working on a roject where I have to implement a method to create a signature using  an alternative to java.security.Signature. So, I don't really have a choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your requirement

> to implement a method to create a signature using an alternative to java.security.Signature

as a whole is questionable (as mentioned in the comments to your question), your solution can be improved.

In particular there is an error in your `myCheckSignature` code:

```
// check if digest1 == digest2
if (digest1 == digest2)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

`(digest1 == digest2)` checks whether you have the *identical array object*, not whether you have *two arrays with equal contents*.

What you really want to do is

```
if (Arrays.equals(digest1, digest2))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

or more compactly

```
return Arrays.equals(digest1, digest2);
```

`Arrays` is a utility class in the package `java.util`.

---

By the way, you do

```
byte[] message = "hello world".getBytes();
```

`getBytes` without explicitly selecting a character encoding may result in different results on different platforms or different Java versions. Something that should not happen in this context!

Comment: If the OP will use your suggestions to create his own signature, he should probably be using at least SHA-256 instead of SHA-1. Taking from the link from caot, it is probably better even to use bcrypt/PBKDF2 (I have no experience using this).

Comment: @TT. I completely agree... he should *not* create his own at all. In particular the issue I pointed out should be obvious for everyone beyond Java 101, so chances are high he [***will** make a major security mistake*](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/18198/16096) eventually.

Comment: Yup he already made a few critical errors and he will indeed make more.

Comment: Regarding the last statement you made about `getBytes`: This should probably be done as `"Hello World".getBytes( "UTF-8" )`.

Comment: thanks a lot @mkl now it works fine for me, it's a stupid mistake I know, in fact it's because I am not familiar with java